# pom.xml not created when android project contains flavours

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I created an Android project which contains flavors. In order to compile my different flavors, I have to set `publishNonDefault` to true. But when I enable flavors, the `android-maven` plugin does not create the pom.xml file (nevertheless, other files are well published on the maven repo).

If I disable the flavors and set `publishNonDefault` to false, the pom.xml file is created.

Is there a solution to publish the different flavors to a maven repo with the pom.xml file?